# How to specify the local directory in INTO OUTFILE-clause?

Tags: clickhouse

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tabname 
INTO OUTFILE '~/results.csv' 
FORMAT CSV
```

How to specify the outfile directory as the local workstation?

Comment: look at example: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/tests/queries/0_stateless/00415_into_outfile.sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to run this command from the client side (local workstation) and define the path to local file:

```sh
clickhouse-client --host ch_server --user test_user --password 12345 \
--query="select * from db_name.table_name INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv' FORMAT CSV"
```

To install [clickhouse-client](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/getting_started/install/) use command:

```sh
sudo apt-get install clickhouse-client
```

Comment: where does it get stored? which tmp is being referred to here?

Comment: I am using mRemoteng to access the clickhouse server from my workstation but I can't dump  the file to my local machine and not the server

Comment: it should be on the machine where you ran the *clickhouse-client*. Run in console the commands *ls -lh /tmp* to check the file existence.
If the file not found try to define another path *~/result.csv* and check its existence by *ls -lh ~*.